# Python why does my variable leap_counter return the UnboundLocalError error message?

Tags: python, scope, variable-declaration

I have the following function to simulate a biochemical system over time. The idea behind the code is to sample time steps then add them to current time.

I have a globally defined start time: `tao = 0.0`

and the following function:

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, epsi):
    t = simulation_timer()
    t.start()
    while tao < tmax:
        evaluate_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
        a0 = (sum(propensity))  # a0 is a numpy.float64
        if a0 == 0.0: 
            break   
        if popul_num.any() < 0: # This isnt working
            print("Number of molecules {} is too small for reaction to fire".format(popul_num))
            break
        # code equation 26 here! 
        for x in range(len(popul_num)):
            # equation 22:
            expctd_net_change = a0*state_change_array[x]
            # equation 24:
            part_diff = derivative(evaluate_propensity, popul_num[x]) 
            # find the partial derivative of propensity with respect to popul_num (number of discrete molecules)
        # need to find a a way to SELECT delta_t before I can code it!
        # equation 26:
        t_step = epsi*a0 / sum(expctd_net_change*part_diff)
        delta_t = optimize.fmin(t_step, 0.00012) 
        print (delta_t)
        lam = (evaluate_propensity*delta_t) 
        rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam) # probability of a reaction firing in the given time period    
        if tao + delta_t > tmax:
            break    
        tao = tao + delta_t 
        leap_counter = tao / delta_t 
        if tao >= 2/a0:     # if tao is big enough
            for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):  
                state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j])   
                #new_propensity = evaluate_propensity
                propensity_check = evaluate_propensity.copy()
                propensity_check[0] += state_change_lambda[0]
                propensity_check[1:] += state_change_lambda  
                for n in range(len(propensity_check)): 
                    if propensity_check[n] - evaluate_propensity[n] >= epsi*a0:   
                        print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                        break  
                    else:
                        popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda                  
                        popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
                        tao_all.append(tao) 
        else:
            t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
            rxn_probability = evaluate_propensity / a0   
            num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
            if tao + t > tmax:      
                tao = tmax
                break
            j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
            tao = tao + t
            popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))  
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
            tao_all.append(tao)
    print("tao:\n", tao)
    print("Molecule numbers:\n", popul_num)
    print("Number of leaps taken:\n", leap_counter)
    t.stop()
    return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao)
```

print(gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, epsi))

Only I get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'leap_counter' referenced before assignment`
When trying to print, or return the number of time steps taken during the simulation, saved in the variable leap_counter and I don't know why. I've tried to change the indentation a bit but that doesn't work. Whats going on and how do I fix it?

EDIT: The following code specifies the value of delta_t in the global environment. I've tried to update it above so I calculate the value of delta_t on each iteration. But then I ran into the problem with the leap counter.

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, delta_t, epsi):
    t = simulation_timer()
    t.start()
    while tao < tmax:
        propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)       
        print("propensity:\n", type(propensity)) 
        a0 = (sum(propensity))
        if a0 == 0.0:
            break
        # if reaction cannot fire corresponding element in rxn_vector should be zero --> tau leaping method 
        if popul_num.any() < 0:
            print("Number of molecules {} is too small for reaction to fire".format(popul_num))
            break   
        lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)
        rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)    
        if tao + delta_t > tmax:
            break
        tao += delta_t
        print("tao:\n", tao)
        print("Molecule numbers:\n", popul_num)
        # divide tao by delta_t to calculate number of leaps
        leap_counter = tao / delta_t   
        if tao >= 2/a0:     
            for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):
                state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
                popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda
                new_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)   
            for n in range(len(new_propensity)):
                propensity_check = propensity + state_change_lambda 
                if propensity_check[n] - new_propensity[n] >= epsi*a0:  
                    print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                    break
                else:
                    popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda     
                    popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
                    tao_all.append(tao)
        else:
            next_t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
            rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
            num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
            if tao + next_t > tmax:      
                tao = tmax
                break
            j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs()
            tao = tao + next_t
            popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))   
    t.stop()
    return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao), leap_counter
```

This code works exactly as I want it to, and what i cant understand is the first function all of a sudden doesnt

Cheers

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation.

Comment: any line before `leap_counter = tao / delta_t` may abort your loop, if your loop even enters at all? Are you sure `tao < tmax`?

Comment: Yes tmax = 5.0 and tao = to 0.0, both set globally

Comment: You haven't accounted for all of the paths and error conditions. What about a `while` or a `for` that executes 0 times? Or a break that exits the loop early? For instance `if popul_num.any() < 0: break` ... and then you don't handle that later.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. There are multiple early break conditions, and we cannot rule out that your function is given input to trigger thesse. See the [ask] page for details. Note that contrary to the description, ``tao`` is a local variable. Is there a reason why you try to access ``leap_counter`` even if it might not have been set?

Comment: Please clarify what you intend your code to do when ``leap_counter`` cannot be calculated. Should it just skip the ``print("Number of leaps taken:\n", leap_counter)`` line or the entire trailing block?

Comment: Once calculated I want to print of the value of leap_counter at the end of the function once the simulation is finished (when tao > tmax)

Comment: That does not answer my question. There are several paths in which ``leap_counter`` is *not* calculated. You cannot print the value of ``leap_counter`` then, because there is none. What do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: Oh! I didn't realise that, would you please be able to point out an example of a path where leap_counter isn't calculated and where the path in the first function differs from the path in the second function?

Comment: No value of ``leap_counter `` is calculated in the case of ``if a0 == 0.0:``, ``if popul_num.any() < 0:``, ``if tao + delta_t > tmax``. I have no idea how the first function differs from the second, since they are large blocks of completely undocumented code – it is difficult enough to roughly work out what one of them does. Please provide a *minimal* reproducible example to help us help you. See the [ask] page for details, as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`leap_counter` is visible (and thus accessible) only inside while loop, try creating it outside the loop (with a reasonable default, preferably).

Comment: Not quite. It needs to be calculated inside the while, delta_t the time step might fluctuate during the simulation so is calculated on each while loop iteration. Moving leap_counter out of the loop references delta_t before its calculated

Comment: @Mike5298 - Is there a reasonable default for that variable? What if `tao` is greater than `tmax` when the function is first called? You didn't mention which line had the error, was it at `print("Number of leaps taken:\n", leap_counter)`? If you are logging variables, would it be useful to default it to `None`? The point is, there can be good reasons for giving this variable a default value outside of the while loop.

Comment: @alagner - I think it would be better to say "assign" rather than "declare" - you don't declare things in python.

Comment: When the function is first called tao = 0.0 and tmax = 20. Sorry the error is on the print line: 'print("Number of leaps taken:\n", leap_counter)'

Comment: @tdelaney right, my wording was imprecise, I fixed the post, thanks. :)

Comment: @Mike5298 regardless where it needs to be calculated, at present the variable is being created in loop's inner scope, and that's where it's visible. Once the loop is over, the scope is left and thus the variable becomes inacessible. It needs to be moved outside of the loop, one way or another, be it a Java-style optional, initial creation before entering the loop or whatever else...